# Adding bar in plot for GrADS?

Tags: plot, grads

Have a nice day everyone,
I'm trying to add a bar for my plot in GrADS software. However, run cbar or set gxout bar kind of commands does not work. How can I possibly add a bar into my plot in GrADS.
Below is attached my plot created using GrADS.

Thanks in advance

Edit: The bar is on right side and shows the range of meteorological data.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you be more specific about 'bar'?

Comment: I'm adding another picture with a bar on.

Comment: Do you have ’cbar.gs' installed in the proper directory? 'cbar.gs' and other usuful scripts can be obtained from http://cola.gmu.edu/grads/gadoc/library.html

Comment: @binzo I cannot download and install "cbar.gs". It doesn't click on cbar.gs or other ones.